# Cannot use INSTALL_ROOT with qmake on Azure DevOps Pipelines in Windows Agent

Tags: qt, azure-devops, cmd, azure-pipelines, qmake

I have a Qt (5.15) project that is building with qmake on Azure DevOps Piplelines on a self-hosted Windows Agent.

My build and install step looks as follows...

```
- script: |
    call C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft Visual Studio"\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat amd64
    call qmake $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    call jom
    call jom install
  workingDirectory: $(Build.BinariesDirectory)
  env:
    INSTALL_ROOT: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

From my understanding, I must use `script` as `vcvarsall.bat` cannot be ran from `powershell`.

The resulting error is on `jom install`:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I have...

- verified `INSTALL_ROOT` is set properly with the `env` step property.
- tried adding a line to set the environment variable, `call set INSTALL_ROOT=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, in the script step. This doesn't change the error.
- ran these exact commands on the same agent from `cmd.exe` and from a `.bat` file. The package is installed as expected.

How do I get the DevOps Windows agent to complete the install task?

---

When I remove `INSTALL_ROOT` environment variable, the install steps succeeds. Obviously, it is not installed in the correct location in this scenario.

Comment: I would first of all advise changing `call C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft Visual Studio"\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat amd64` to ```call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64```. Then I would remove `call` from the start of each of the other lines as well as including the file extensions  for `qmake.exe` and `jom.exe` and for robustness, their full paths too, e.g. `"C:\Qt\Qt5.15.15\5.15\Tools\QtCreator\bin\qmake.exe" $(Build.SourcesDirectory)` `"C:\Qt\Qt5.15.15\5.15\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" install`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `qmake` will append `C:` to the front of the `INSTALL_ROOT` variable when generating the directives in the `Makefile`.

In order to use `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, the drive prefix must be stripped.